# Xcode: can't build, duplicate symbol - ld: 305 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm having trouble building my Xcode project to device and simulator. I'm receiving a bunch of duplicate symbol errors for CrashlyticsFramework and Fabric.framework.

Error looks something like this:

```
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CLSIcon._prerendered in:
    /Users/Abdi/Desktop/app-ios/Pods/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSIcon.o)
    /Users/Abdi/Desktop/bento-ios/Fabric.framework/Fabric(CLSIcon.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CLSIcon._size in:
    /Users/Abdi/Desktop/app-ios/Pods/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSIcon.o)
    /Users/Abdi/Desktop/app-ios/Fabric.framework/Fabric(CLSIcon.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CLSIcon in:
    /Users/Abdi/Desktop/app-ios/Pods/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSIcon.o)
    /Users/Abdi/Desktop/bento-ios/Fabric.framework/Fabric(CLSIcon.o)
ld: 305 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I think if you use Fabric, you don't need to specifically include Crashlytics anymore. Drop crashlytics from your podfile, `pod install`, and then try building again.

Comment: Please, mark the answer as accepted If helped you. Thanks

Comment: 2 years 3 months too late, but here you go!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I just realized that **Answers code is included in the 'Crashlytics' pod**, so no need to add the 'Answers' pod. Was a little brainfuck to me. They should update their docs.

Comment: Nice catch! For people having this problem, the sample codes found in the Fabric docs will tell you to import Answers. Replace that with import Crashlytics

Comment: This is still working as of Xcode 7.2.1, Fabric 1.6.7 and Crashlytics 3.7.0

Comment: this was very confusing, it looks like they did add a note now about it being included in their docs, but they should definitely update this page https://fabric.io/kits/ios/answers/install

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions in here solved the problem for our machines locally and on the CI server -> https://github.com/zergtmn/Fabric/issues/5

Specifically, insuring that the Fabric Mac app was installed and updating the podfile:

```
pod 'Fabric/Core', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Fabric/Crashlytics', '~> 1.2'
```

Then finally updating the Crashlytics run script from XCode:

```
./Pods/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run YOUR_API_KEY YOUR_API_SECRET
```